# Query min column header while excluding blanks and handling duplicates

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, min, google-query-language

I have the following table.

| Name | Score A | Score B | Score C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob |  | 8 | 6 |
| Sue | 9 | 12 | 9 |
| Joe | 11 | 2 |  |
| Susan | 7 | 9 | 10 |
| Tim | 10 | 12 | 4 |
| Ellie | 9 | 8 | 7 |

In my actual table there are about 2k rows.

I am trying to get the min score (excluding blanks & handles duplicate scores) for each person into another column using the `QUERY` formula or `ARRAYFORMULA`, really to avoid entering a formula for each row.

As I do currently have this

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(MIN(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))
```

But that involves dragging down through each cell, as I do this on a few sheets that have circa 2k rows, it's very slow when inputting new data.

This should be the end result

| Name | Score A | Score B | Score C |  | Min Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob |  | 8 | 6 |  | Score C |
| Sue | 9 | 12 | 9 |  | Score A |
| Joe | 11 | 2 |  |  | Score B |
| Susan | 7 | 9 | 10 |  | Score A |
| Tim | 10 | 12 | 4 |  | Score C |
| Ellie | 9 | 8 | 7 |  | Score C |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORTN(SORT(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 IF(B2:D="",,B1:D1&"×"&B2:D&"×"&ROW(B2:D))), 
 "where Col1 is not null", ), 
 "×"), 3, 1, 2, 1), 9^9, 2, 3, 1),, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Bravo Player0 ... but I think also an illustration of my point that LAMBDA will reduce the complexity of problems like this when it's generally available.

Comment: `SORTN(SORT` is key, It was such an uncommon situation, however I remember applying this approach, looking forward for what we can do `LAMBDA` .

Comment: @TheGodofBiscuits it surely will but without full rollout it's still questionable to show ppl if half of them cant use it yet

Answer (score 0):

The following answer employs three of the newest set of functions that are still being rolled out by Google so you might not be able to use it right now, but in a few weeks when they're fully rolled out you definitely will (this worked using the Android version of Sheets just now for me):

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A),byrow(B2:D,lambda(row,xlookup(min(row),row,B1:D1))),))
```

Assuming the names are in column A, this should give a result for every row which has a name in it. I'm sure there are other ways of doing this, but these 'row/column-wise' problems are really ideal use-cases for LAMBDA and its helper functions like BYROW.

Comment: It didn't work for me in Google sheets android, can you share more info?

Comment: I'm getting a `Unknown function: 'BYROW'` error with that formula

Comment: Looks like you don't have access to some/all of the new functions yet - like I said, they're not fully rolled out yet. More info here: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/08/named-functions-google-sheets.html?m=1